# Getting reference error (in chrome debugger) when using Math.floor method

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, referenceerror

Hi when I run this function the variable `index` becomes a

```
reference error: index is not defined at eval
```

My code:

```
function getReferenceDate(){
  //let today = "01/18/2019"
  var now = moment();
  let day = now.day()
  let refOffset = day-1
  now.day()!=0?refOffset = (day-1):refOffset=6
  now.subtract(refOffset,"days")
  return now
}

function getNextIndex(first, frequency){
  let ref = getReferenceDate()
  let thisFirst = moment(first)
  let isBefore = thisFirst.isBefore(ref,"days")
  if(isBefore){
    let diff = ref.diff(thisFirst,"days")
    let nextIndex = Math.abs(Math.floor(((frequency*7)-diff)/7))%frequency
    return nextIndex
  }else{
    let diff = thisFirst.diff(ref,"days")
    let index =(diff+1)/7
    index = Math.floor(index)
    return index
  }
}

getNextIndex("20190218",1)
```

Obviously `index` should resolve to an integer and returned by the function.  But all I get is the error?
I am using `moment.js` which is where the `diff` and `moment` methods come from.

EDIT: actually it is only the Chrome debugger that the error displays just after stepping out of the

`index = Math.floor(index)`

and to the next line (return..).  After a bit of testing I am finding that I am actually end up getting a the result I expected.  Perhaps it is a nuance of the debugger?

Comment: Hi welcome to StackOverflow. Please add your error what you're getting, so we can have a better look at it.

Comment: Your code uses the functions "diff" and "moment" that we have no idea where they come from. The issue is probably there.

Comment: Please [edit] post with real [MCVE]. It is very unlikely that the code posted so far will produce that error as there is not `eval` anywhere.